# All lists with three repeating elements

Tags: prolog

All lists with one single element is easy to define using the [Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#prologue):

```
?- maplist(=(_),L).
   L = []
;  L = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A]
;  ... .
```

So this element is repeated over and over again.  Fine.
But how can I define all lists that repeat three elements in always the same order? Such that I get as answer:

```
?- Query_with_L.
   L = []
;  L = [_A]
;  L = [_A,_B]
;  L = [_A,_B,_C]
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_A]
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_A,_B]
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_A,_B,_C]
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_A,_B,_C,_A]
;  ... .
?- L = [a,_,_,b|_], Query_with_L.
   false.
?- L = [_,a,_,_,b|_], Query_with_L.
   false.
?- L = [_,_,a,_,_,b|_], Query_with_L.
   false.
```

All this just using the [Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#prologue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimal:

```
repeat3(Es) :-
    append(Es, _, [_,_,_|Es]).
```

Answer (score 6):

Single clause, not subject to occurs-check:

```
repeat3(Es) :-
    append([_,_,_], Es, Fs),
    append(Es, [_,_,_], Fs).
```

Finally:

```
repeat3(Es) :-
    append(Es, [_,_,_], [_,_,_|Es]).
```

Comment: Ingenious indeed!

Comment: Better, but still much too large.

Comment: The shortest with `append/3`.

Comment: Shorter indeed, but not shortest.

Comment: And please, use a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

STO:

```
repeat3(Es) :-
    append([_,_,_], Fs, Fs),
    append(Es, _, Fs).
```

NSTO:

```
repeat3(Es) :-
    repeat3(_, _, _, Es).

repeat3(_, _, _, []).
repeat3(E0, _, _, [E0]).
repeat3(E0, E, _, [E0,E]).
repeat3(E0, E1, E, [E0,E1,E|Es]) :-
    repeat3(E0, E1, E, Es).
```

Or:

```
repeat3(Es) :-
    repeat([_,_,_], Es).

repeat(Fs0, Es0) :-
    append(Fs1, Fs, Fs0),
    append(Fs1, Es, Es0),
    repeat(Fs0, Fs, Es).

repeat(_, [_|_], []).
repeat(Fs0, [], Es) :-
    repeat(Fs0, Es).
```

Comment: Still much too long...

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution, maybe not short enough:

```
repeat(A, B, C, L) :- append(L, _, [A,B,C]).
repeat(A, B, C, [A,B,C|[D|L]]) :-  repeat(A, B, C, [D|L]).
```

Examples:

```
?- repeat(A, B, C, L).
L = [] ;
L = [A] ;
L = [A, B] ;
L = [A, B, C] ;
L = [A, B, C, A] ;
L = [A, B, C, A, B] ;
L = [A, B, C, A, B, C] ;
L = [A, B, C, A, B, C, A] 
... .

?- L = [a,_,_,b|_], repeat(A, B, C, L).
false.

?- L = [_,a,_,_,b|_], repeat(A, B, C, L).
false.

?- L = [_,_,a,_,_,b|_], repeat(A, B, C, L).
false.
```

Comment: Good direction, yet ...

Answer (score 4):

Brevis:

```
repeat3(Es) :-
    repeat3(_, _, _, Es).

repeat3(_, _, _, []).
repeat3(E0, E1, E, [E0|Es]) :-
    repeat3(E1, E, E0, Es).
```

With `append/3`:

```
repeat3(Es) :-
    repeat([_,_,_], Es).

repeat(_, []).
repeat([E|Fs0], [E|Es]) :-
    append(Fs0, [E], Fs),
    repeat(Fs, Es).
```

Comment: Much too long since the Prolog prologue is not used. But I like this kind of rotation.

Comment: Added `append/3` solution.

Comment: This is even longer ....

Comment: The first solution will benefit from first-argument indexing on the `Es` list.

Answer (score 3):

```
repeats_len_list(Len, Lst) :-
    length(F, Len),
    % Loop through F, then start afresh with F
    repeats_len_list_(Lst, F, F).

repeats_len_list_([], _, _).
% U means upto, F means full
repeats_len_list_([H|T], U, F) :-
    repeats_len_list_u_(U, F, [H|T]).

repeats_len_list_u_([], F, T) :-
    repeats_len_list_fresh_(F, T).
repeats_len_list_u_([H|U], F, [H|T]) :-
    repeats_len_list_t_(T, F, U).

repeats_len_list_t_([], _, _).
repeats_len_list_t_([H|T], F, U) :-
    % Next element
    repeats_len_list_u_(U, F, [H|T]).

% Guarding against empty-list F, which would infinite-loop
repeats_len_list_fresh_([FH|FT], T) :-
    % Start again with full F
    repeats_len_list_u_([FH|FT], [FH|FT], T).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- repeats_len_list(3, L).
L = [] ;
L = [_] ;
L = [_, _] ;
L = [_, _, _] ;
L = [_A, _, _, _A] ;
L = [_A, _B, _, _A, _B] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C] ;

?- L = [a,_,_,b|_], repeats_len_list(3, L).
false.

?- L = [_,a,_,_,b|_], repeats_len_list(3, L).
false.

?- L = [_,_,a,_,_,b|_], repeats_len_list(3, L).
false.

% No unwanted choicepoint
?- repeats_len_list(3, [a,b,c,A]).
A = a.
```

Comment: Correct, yet could this be shorter using the Prolog prologue?  I mean, significantly shorter. Also note that length/2 isn't needed, as one could hard code that very length.

Answer (score 3):

A shorter version than my previous answer, removing the length flexibility, and with worse determinism:

```
repeats3([]).
repeats3([H|T]) :-
    F = [_, _, _],
    repeats3_(F, F, [H|T]).

repeats3_([], F, L) :-
    repeats3_(F, F, L).
repeats3_([H|_], _, [H]).
repeats3_([H|R], F, [H|T]) :-
    repeats3_(R, F, T).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- repeats3(L).
L = [] ;
L = [_] ;
L = [_, _] ;
L = [_, _, _] ;
L = [_A, _, _, _A] ;
L = [_A, _B, _, _A, _B] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C, _A, _B, _C] ;

?- L = [a,_,_,b|_], repeats3(L).
false.

?- L = [_,a,_,_,b|_], repeats3(L).
false.

?- L = [_,_,a,_,_,b|_], repeats3(L).
false.

% Has unwanted choicepoint
?- repeats3([a,b,c,A]).
A = a ;
false.
```

Comment: Shorter, but still it can be much much shorter.

Answer (score 3):

A variant of @Notoria's STO approach:

```
?- ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], append(L,_,ABCs).
   ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], L = []
;  ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], L = [A]
;  ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], L = [A,B]
;  ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], L = [A,B,C]
;  ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], L = [A,B,C,A]
;  ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], L = [A,B,C,A,B]
;  ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], L = [A,B,C,A,B,C]
;  ABCs = [A,B,C|ABCs], L = [A,B,C,A,B,C,A]
;  ... .
```

Comment: Succeeds incorrectly for `L="abcabcx",` in Tau (which does have conforming unification).

Comment: @false. I tried `?- L = "abcabcx", Xs = [A,B,C|Xs], append(L,_,Xs).` with Scryer and SWI. Both answered `false`. What's going on? What's up with Tau?

Comment: @false. I see that `; ... .` is better than `...` for indicating an incomplete enumeration of answers in most cases. OTOH, `... /0` might be a residual goal. A few layout chars before the final `.` might be useful to show that.

Comment: Using a residual goal that does not have any arguments seems to be an odd choice. Where should that happen? Same for all the other constructs of quads.

Comment: W.r.t. Tau, please [try it](http://tau-prolog.org/). Also see [#82](https://github.com/tau-prolog/tau-prolog/issues/82).

Comment: @false. Odd indeed. It *might* be a way of letting the top-level show if `full_answer/0` in `library(clpfd)` is defined. OTOH it should always be defined IMO.

Answer (score 2):

This uses rational trees and it doesn't work if `occurs check` is enabled.

```
repeat(N, Es) :-
    length(Fs0, N),
    N > 0,
    append(Fs0, Fs, Fs),
    foldl(pop, Es, Fs, _).

pop(E, [E|Es], Es).
```

Without rational term:

```
repeat(N, Es) :-
    length(Fs0, N),
    foldl(step(Fs0), Es, [], _).

step(Fs, E, [], Es) :-
    Fs = [E|Es].
step(_, E, [E|Es], Es).
```

Query:

```
?- repeat(3, L).
   L=[]
;  L=[_A]
;  L=[_A,_B]
;  L=[_A,_B,_C]
;  L=[_A,_B,_C,_A]
;  ... .
?- L = [a,_,_,b|_], repeat(3, L).
   false.
?- L = [_,a,_,_,b|_], repeat(3, L).
   false.
?- L = [_,_,a,_,_,b|_], repeat(3, L).
   false.
```

Comment: While ignoring your first solution as it is STO, and does not work in a conforming implementation like Tau regardless of the occurs check...

Comment: ...your second solution is indeed quite nice, but it uses `foldl/4` which so far is not part of the Prolog prologue. And length/2 adds unwanted generality. You definitely could reduce the size of your program!

Comment: The second solution can be specialized to not use `foldl/4` but it wouldn't be much shorter or different.

Comment: Right, but it could be much much shorter using the Prolog prologue as it stands currently.

Comment: BTW, it's **rational trees** not terms.